# Can diffusion occur without thermal motion of molecules?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-chemistry

If I would ask: What are the Basic mechanisms of diffusion? I would get the answer: Because of thermal Brownian Motion.

But are there other causes besides Brownian motion for Diffusion?

Can Diffusion be explained on Quantum-mechanical Basis?

Comment: for "quantum effects in diffusion" have a look here  https://phys.org/news/2015-10-quantum-tunneling-diffusion-hydrogen-atoms-ice.html

Comment: What other causes do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

"But are there other causes besides Brownian motion for Diffusion?"
"Can Diffusion be explained on Quantum-mechanical Basis?"

It depends on the physical system you are thinking of (ie. what you mean by "difussion"). The Brownian motion of a particle in a fluid is dominated by thermal motion and quantum-mechanical effects are not really needed to describe this.

However, there are systems where "quantum-hopping" is important. Consider an impurity or a vacancy diffusing in a crystal lattice, this process occurs in discrete jumps properly described by QM.